# How to add extra comment on top of generated ts file? (like eslint disable statements)

Tags: reinforced-typings

I'm using ReinforcedTypings 1.6.2 and I'm trying to add extra comments on top of exported ts file.
How can I do that?

e.g

```
/* eslint-disable max-classes-per-file */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-inferrable-types */
```

somewhere before or after

```
//     This code was generated by a Reinforced.Typings tool.
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
```

Thank you

Comment: Our of curiosity, why would you want some comments added to files that are not tracked by your VCS and are thus not part of the code base of your project?

Comment: They are tracked and part of the code base

Comment: Maybe it explains why there is no obvious option to add comments on top of exported files: because they are not supposed to be tracked and thus there is no need for comments that would say "don't modify this file". :)

Comment: "Don't modify this file" is added by the library. But yes I get your point. I added file to .eslintignore, thanks. I let the question open if anyone has the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I thought that the comment was what you wanted to add at the top of the file. I misunderstood.